# Dead Store to local Variable in Java

Tags: java, garbage-collection

What exactly is the mechanism behind the bug- dead store to a local variable.. ??

Some say that dead store to variable bug occurs when you assign a value to variable but do not use that variable again in that code block/ function (I am facing the bug of same kind).

```
void foo(){
String str = someObj.getString();
//some code but str is never used after assignment...
}
```

But there is also a case where you tend to initialize a variable with a value, but later in the subsequent instruction, you replace the value of the variable with some other value.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list = someobj.getList();
```

In this case, object created by new ArrayList<>() is never used which is also defined as dead store.

We have a mechanism of garbage collection in java, which looks after such orphan objects and is responsible to optimize the memory.
So if garbage collection takes care of memory leaks, then why do we get this bug of dead store to local variable?

can garbage collector play any role in this bug?

Its pretty clear that GC is not able to identify such dead stores!! But then, why can GC not able to identify it??

Note:I am of the opinion, developers should avoid such mistakes of assigning values which are never used further. But still this is one doubt that has come in my mind and now i want a well structured and a technical answer to it.. ;)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question appears to be too broad for this site. We are specialized in solving well-defined technical issues instead of writing essays on Java garbage collection (unless that is required to solve a specific technical issue in the code posted by the one who asked the question). See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GC is perfectly fine with that. This is not really a bug. Simply an inefficiency: you're consuming CPU time and memory for nothing.

It can also be an indication of a bug: if you (or a colleague before you) added this instruction, but you don't use the variable later, it might mean that you forgot something in the algorithm.